# Trying to pass value from controller to view and then view to partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi i am trying to pass value from controller to view and then view to partial view. i have a 'layout' master page  where i have a partial page '@Html.Partial("Header")'.
In my home controller i am getting Session[CommonConstants.SESSION_USER_ID].ToString().
now i want to send this value from home controller to partial view 'Header.cshtml' which is part of 'layout' master page
home controller

storing value in `ViewBag.session = Session[CommonConstants.SESSION_USER_ID];`
 from here passing value in

home.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@ViewBag.session
```

Now in _Layout.cshtml there is partial page `@Html.Partial("Header")`
i want to send `"@ViewBag.session"` value in `Header.cshtml`.

How can i achieve it any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you not just access the value in the `Header.cshtml` file in exactly the same way? You may just need to null check it?

Comment: @ste-fu thanks it's working .i haven't tried as you have said earlier thanx for reminding..